# How to get data from url in list view using json in ios 4.3 simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios4

I am just beginner in ios using xcode 3.2,i want to get data from url that I'm getting the JSON format data like this,how to display Windows Live ID,Google with Image,loginUrl,logoutUr..

**JSON**

```
0
Name : "Windows Live™ ID"

LoginUrl : ""

LogoutUrl : ""

ImageUrl : ""

EmailAddressSuffixes

1

Name : "Google"

LoginUrl : ""

LogoutUrl : ""

ImageUrl : ""

EmailAddressSuffixes

2

Name : "Yahoo!"

LoginUrl : ""

LogoutUrl : ""

ImageUrl : ""

EmailAddressSuffixes
```

What i have to write in .h file and .m file,Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where you want to display this data?means in tableview?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response,exactly i want to display the data in tableview

Comment: once check my answer it'l work fine.

Comment: Okay....i will implement your code and let you know

Comment: sorry i can't get the result,can you please give the code step by step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SBJson](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/) for parse json. add SBJson classes in your project and than use this code to parse the json

```
-(void)WBCalled
{

    ExampleAppDataObject* theDataObject = [self theAppDataObject];

    //this code is used to send and retrive data from webservices
    NSString *post =@"";

    //NSLog(@"post is:%@",post);

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@""];

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    if ([response statusCode] >=200 && [response statusCode] <300)
    {
        NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        // NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);

        SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];   //here you are using sbjson library to parse json data
        NSDictionary *jsonData = (NSDictionary *) [jsonParser objectWithString:responseData error:nil];
        NSLog(@"full jsonData : %@",jsonData);   //this dictionary contain all the data of your json response you can conver this data in NSString or NSArray according to your need

        NSString *message = (NSString *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"Message"];

        if (message.length !=0) {
            [self alertStatus:message :@"Status"];
        }


    } else {
        if (error) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        [self alertStatus:@"Connection Failed" :@"Data Sending Failed!"];
    }

}
-(void) alertStatus:(NSString *)msg :(NSString *)title
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                        message:msg
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [alertView show];
}
```

Comment: Hi Dilip,i'm getting an error like SVProgressHUD,ExampleAppDataObject undeclared

Comment: aah , sorry just delete `[SVProgressHUD dismiss];`. its for display HUD but it's not needed. i have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

for this once try like this,use this one in tableview `cellForRowAtIndex` method

if you want to get the dictionary then use,

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict=[jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

if you want to get string value then use this one,

```
NSString * LoginUrl=[[jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"LoginUrl"];
```

if you want to get all the data then use one for loop and save that data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSURLConnection (or) Json libarary to parse data received from server.

Below is the sample code of parsing JSON using NSURL connection:

In viewDidLoad:

```
NSString *strConfirmChallenge = [URL string];

     strConfirmChallenge = [strConfirmChallenge stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"strConfirmChallenge=%@",strConfirmChallenge);

    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:strConfirmChallenge];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                                       timeoutInterval:60];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection =[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];


    //Delegate methods

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
        responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    }

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
        [responseData appendData:data];
    }

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
        //NSLog(@"Failed to get data");
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
        UIAlertView *myalert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Info" message:@"Service error" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [myalert show];
    }

    - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    {
        dispatch_async(kBgQue, ^{
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(parseData:)
                                   withObject:responseData
                                waitUntilDone:YES];
        });
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
    }



    //parsing data


    -(void)parseData:(NSData *)data{
         NSError *error;
            NSDictionary *data = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:(0) error:&error];

            if(error){
                //NSLog(@"JSon Error %@",[error localizedDescription]);
                UIAlertView *myalert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Info" message:@"Service error" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                [myalert show];

            }else{
                NSDictionary *datDetails = (NSDictionary *) [data objectForKey:@"your key"];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response,NSJSONSerialization is not supported in xcode 3.2

Comment: @user2148679, use SBJson as suggested by Dilip.